# Australian Police Radio Frequency

Tags: frequency, emergency

Does any one know or have a frequency chart with Australian Emergency services?

Comment: This question is about non-Amateur radio, and is not about radio technology in general, so it is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you listen to country Police on HF you are unlikely to be able to hear anything - most states have gone digital now, and APCO25 encrypted.

They're no fun...